# Pass data between ViewControllers

Tags: ios, swift, swift3

Am trying to pass data between  ViewControllers and  am not using storyboard so i cannot use `prepareForSegue` method here is what i have done:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    var vc = productDetailViewController()
    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(productDetailViewController(), animated: true)
    vc.product = self.shoes[indexPath.row]
}
```

Comment: And... is it not working? What is the result? Perhaps you can clarify what is happening and what your actual question is.

Comment: It is not working the `productDetailViewController`  `product` return `nil`

Answer (score 1):

You are doing two mistakes here:

1) Trying to set value in vc but sending a new instance of view controller.

2) Setting value to the controller after it already been pushed.

So, try as below :

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

var vc = productDetailViewController()

vc.product = self.shoes[indexPath.row]

self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc,     animated: true)

}
```

Comment: Ugh... I missed that. Absolutely, replacing `pushViewController(productDetailViewController(), ...` with `pushViewController(vc, ...` is key.

Answer (score 0):

Swap the last two lines... Your `productDetailViewController` likely is looking for product data on initialization, which has already occurred when it's been pushed.

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    // instantiate the new VC
    var vc = productDetailViewController()

    // set the data in the new VC first
    vc.product = self.shoes[indexPath.row]

    // then "show" the new VC --- NOT a new instance of productDetailViewController()
   //self.navigationController?.pushViewController(productDetailViewController(), animated: true)</s>
    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
}
```

Comment: OK ... when you debug your code... At this line: `vc.product = self.shoes[indexPath.row]` what is the value of `self.shoes[indexPath.row]`?